# how to resize Image View based on the size of the Image?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

i am loading a image from Parse and loading the images into a UITableViewCell and i want to size the Image View based on the size of the image that is retrieved. How can i do this? If you need an example, i think instagram has different image views in size.

Comment: You could update the autolayout constraint programmatically of UIImageView OR create UIImageView programmatically (add as subview) depending upon the size of image.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this link.. It may helpful for you..

http://candycode.io/dynamic-uitableview-height-for-downloaded-images/

Answer (score 0):

You can resize image View by using custom `UITableViewCell`, i can share example code if you want to implement custom cell.

Create New Nib for `CustomCell` and Add `IBOutlet` for `UILabel`(if required) and `UIImageView`.

```
@interface CustomTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *nameLabel;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *thumbnailImageView;
@end
```

Then in class where you returning cell, do following implementation for using Custom Cell

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString * simpleTableIdentifier = @"CustomTableViewCell";

    CustomTableViewCell *cell = (CustomTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    cell.nameLabel.text = @"If you want to set any text";
    [cell.thumbnailImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Replace Image Name"]];
    cell.thumbnailImageView.frame = CustomFrameYouWantToSet;
    return cell;
}
```

You can also refer to following tutorials for implementing Custom TableViewCell.
http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-crafting-custom-uitableview-cells--mobile-15702

Comment: @farhan i have edited my answer, hope i would be helpful for you.